# Nodejs browser-sync install issue

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu, browser-sync

I am using Windows Ubuntu bash terminal
Trying to install `browser-sync` for nodejs and after the command

`npm install -g browser-sync`.

I am getting an error message:

> : not foundram Files/nodejs/npm: 3: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: :
>   not foundram Files/nodejs/npm: 5: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm:
>   /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: 6: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm:
>   Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")

Path is set `C:\Users\vladi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\` and that path is correct

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: One more thing.When I execute the command npm --version it is giving me the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
then i made some changes to my PATH in my ~/.profile

PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH"

Close the bash, re-open it and run the command again npm install -g browser-sync

It worked like a charm